# Getting onChange value to be of generic type without type assertion in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange, typescript-generics

I'v created a generic react component with option elements like this:
      import * as React from "react";

```
  export interface Option {
    value: string;
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
  }

  export interface SelectProps<CustomOption extends Option> {
    options: CustomOption[];
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
    selectedValue: string;
  }

  export const Select: React.FunctionComponent<SelectProps<Option>> = (props): JSX.Element => {
    const options = props.options.map(o => {
      return (
        <option key={o.value} value={o.value} disabled={o.disabled}>
          {o.label}
        </option>
      );
    });

    return (
      <select onChange={props.onChange} value={props.selectedValue}>
        {options}
      </select>
    );
  };
```

I'm using this like this:

```
  type OptionValues = "FOO" | "BAR" | "BAZ" | "NO_ANSWER";

  const createSelect = (selectedOption: OptionValues, onChange: (v: OptionValues) => void): JSX.Element => {
    const changeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => onChange(event.currentTarget.value as OptionValues);
    interface SelectOptions extends Option {
      value: OptionValues;
    }

    const selectProps: SelectProps<SelectOptions> = {
      onChange: changeHandler,
      selectedValue: selectedOption,
      options: [
        {
          value: "FOO",
          label: "foo"
        },
        {
          value: "BAR",
          label: "bar"
        },
        {
          value: "BAZ",
          label: "baz"
        },
        {
          value: "NO_ANSWER",
          label: " -- ",
          disabled: true
        }
      ]
    };
    return <Select {...selectProps} />;
  };
```

Is there any way to avoid using type assertion in the changeHandler.
`event.currentTarget.value as OptionValues`. Also I see that the whole createSelect suddenly is very verbose with references to OptionValues everywhere, but I guess there is no way around it. Alternative ways to solve the problem is also welcomed. That is making sure value is of predetermined types.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you actually need a type-guard, as typescript is not that smart.

If your Select component deep down, is just what I think it is, it will never work.

See [typeguards](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-type-guards/)

```
type OptionValues = 'FOO' | 'BAR' | 'BAZ' | 'NO_ANSWER'

const isOptionValue = (value: unknown): value is OptionValues =>
  typeof value === 'string' && ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ', 'NO_ANSWER'].includes(value)

  const createSelect = (selectedOption: OptionValues, onChange: (v: OptionValues) => void): JSX.Element => {
    const changeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
        const value = event.currentTarget.value
        if(isOptionValue(value))
         onChange(value);
    }
...
```